# how to apply hibernate child criteria restrictions to java list?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
class A{
     String name;
     List<B> b;
     boolean ra;
}

 class B{
    boolean rb;  
    int a;
        }
```

i want to add  child criteria that everything from List of b will come whhose value of boolean rb is false in class b.

```
   Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class,"a");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("a.name","hi", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```

how add this child criteria that will get some elements from list of b which contain value of rb is false?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases as described in the Hibernate documentation

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createAlias("kittens", "kt")
    .createAlias("mate", "mt")
    .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("kt.name", "mt.name") )
    .list();
```

So in your case you want to create alias for ´b´.

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class,"a");
    criteria.createAlias('b', 'b');
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq('b.rb', false));
    ...
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html